# Replacing string with variable in wordpress LaTeX shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, latex, str-replace, shortcode

I am building a shortcode that replaces some text in a [LaTex] shortcode using some pre-saved variables.

The shortcode is entered as:

```
[dynamic_latex][latex s=3]Q1A^{2}+5=Q1B[/latex][/dynamic_latex]
```

where Q1A and Q1B should be replaced with the stored user meta.

```
function latex_find_repalce($atts, $content, $tag) {
    global $random_coefficient_A;
    global $random_coefficient_B;
    $new_LaTeX = str_replace('$a', $random_coefficient_A, $content);
    $new_LaTeX = str_replace('$b', $random_coefficient_B, $new_LaTeX);

    $keys = ['Q1A', 'Q1B', 'Q1C', 'Q1D', 'Q1E', 'Q1F', 'Q1G', 'Q2A', 'Q2B', 'Q2C', 'Q2D', 'Q2E', 'Q2F', 'Q2G', 'Q3A', 'Q3B', 'Q3C', 'Q3D', 'Q3E', 'Q3F', 'Q3G']; //Add as many as needed

    foreach($keys as $key) {
        $question_key = "key_{$key}"; //The key for the stored number 
        $replace_meta = get_user_meta( $user_id, $question_key, true );
        $new_LaTeX = str_replace($key, $replace_meta, $new_LaTeX);

    }//foreach

return '<span>' . do_shortcode($new_LaTeX) . '</span>';

}
add_shortcode('dynamic_latex', 'latex_find_repalce');
```

It seems to delete the keys in question, but instead of replacing with anything it just leaves it blank. How do I correctly replace the key (Q1A) with it's stored variable? Or am I missing something else?  Thanks!

Comment: `$new_LaTeX` is used before its initialized. That looks odd.

Comment: Ah. It is actually used before this. I removed it to keep it clean. These lines are above the $keys array;  
    $new_LaTeX = str_replace('$a', $random_coefficient_A, $content);
  $new_LaTeX = str_replace('$b', $random_coefficient_B, $new_LaTeX);

Comment: I don't see that in this code.

Comment: I've added it now

Comment: The only reason why this could happen is when users don't actually have any metadata stored under those keys. (or `$replaced_meta` comes back empty for other reasons)

Comment: There is metadata stored in those keys, so there must be something wrong with $replaced_meta.

Comment: Do a `die(var_dump($replaced_meta))` after you've called `get_user_meta` to see what you've got.

Comment: It's displaying NULL. Looks like that's the problem!

Answer (score 0):

$user_id was not defined in the function.

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
```

Thanks for the help! I'd been fighting this for hours